# How do Fix the exception error where my mic does not pick up an input properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, speech-recognition

I am building a weak Ai platform in the form of siri and google assistant,however, every time i run my code it always returns 'sorry i did not catch that' - the exception instead of picking up an input via my microphone.I am following a YouTube tutorial to build this as i am fairly new to python and therefore i have no clue on what the problem is as it seems to work fine for the guy within the tutorial.Can someone please walk me through fixing this?Thanks

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import datetime
import wikipedia
import webbrowser
import os
import smtplib
import pythoncom

print("Initializing Karren")

MASTER = "Nadeem"

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)

def speak(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()


def wishMe():
    hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)

    if hour>=0 and hour <12:
        speak("Good Morning" + MASTER)

    elif hour>=12 and hour<18:
        speak("Good Afternoon" + MASTER)
    else:
        speak("Good Evening" + MASTER)


    speak("How may I assist you?")

def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try :
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language ='en-uk')
            print(f"user said: {query}\n")

        except Exception as e:
            print("Sorry i didn't catch that...")

speak("Initializing Karren...")
wishMe()
query = takeCommand()

#Logic
if query:
    if 'wikipedia' in query.lower():
        speak('Searching wikipedia...')
        query = query.replace("wikipedia", "")
        results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences =2)
        print(results)
        speak(results)


    if 'open youtube' in query.lower():
        webbrowser.open("youtube.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is the updated code @iSavageSkull

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import datetime
import wikipedia
import webbrowser
import os
import smtplib
import pythoncom

print("Initializing Karren")

MASTER = "Nadeem"

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)

def speak(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()


def wishMe():
    hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)

    if hour>=0 and hour <12:
        speak("Good Morning" + MASTER)

    elif hour>=12 and hour<18:
        speak("Good Afternoon" + MASTER)
    else:
        speak("Good Evening" + MASTER)


    speak("How may I assist you?")

def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try :
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language ='en-uk')
        print(f"user said: {query}\n")

    except Exception as e:
        print("Sorry i didn't catch that...")

speak("Initializing Karren...")
wishMe()
query = takeCommand()

#Logic
if query:
    if 'wikipedia' in query.lower():
        speak('Searching wikipedia...')
        query = query.replace("wikipedia", "")
        results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences =2)
        print(results)
        speak(results)


    if 'open youtube' in query.lower():
        webbrowser.open("youtube.com")
```

**ERROR YOU HAVE DONE HERE:**

1. Under `def takeCommand()`, the `print(f"user said: {query}\n")` is indented wrongly, it should be indented properly.
2. Under the same `def takeCommand()` the,

```
    except Exception as e:
        print("Sorry i didn't catch that...")
```

Here again, it is and indentation Error, and that's why it always keeps printing Errror, even though the code is producing a legit output

Run my updated code of yours, and the programs works fine!!!